# Existe una manera de hacer un foreach a una cadena de strings?

Tags: php, string, variables, foreach

Tengo una cadena de string en una variable esta se llama

**$texto**
Y quiero trabajo con ella por foreacha

ejemplo esto

```
foreach($texto as $fila){

}
```

Y bueno la cosa es que no me deja trabajarlo me sale el síguente error

---

- Expected type 'iterable|object'. Found 'string'

---

---

***O si alguien me explicaría el porque me sucede ese error***

Comment: PHP, a diferencia de algunos otros lenguajes, no puede iterar directamente sobre un string, sin embargo es muy fácil convertirlo en un iterable (array), por ejemplo usando [str_split](https://www.php.net/str_split): `foreach(str_split($texto) as $fila)`. Si hay otro tipo de separador, como coma u otro, usa `explode()`, como te sugieren en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes en la variable un texto como por ejemplo:

```
$texto = "casa,mesa,silla,coche";
```

Podrias usar la función [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) para crear un array con las palabras. Tal que así:

```
$objetos = explode(",", $texto);
echo $objetos[0];  //"casa"
```

Espero que te sirva.

Edito: el error que te da es que un string no es un elemento iterable.